# Extract data from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, http

I want to extract data from iframe and print to any class using JavaScript

Example:

```js
var iBody = $("#getDataJson").contents().find("pre");
$('#hedl').html(iBody);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="getDataJson" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me?fields=id"></iframe>
```

This will result in data in Json format, I want to extract any value from them via JavaScript and print them to any class using

I tried it on a file on the localhost and work without any problems, but when adding a remote link ( https:// ) does not work :(

any suggestions?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use a get request for the JSON?

Comment: You cannot extract data from an IFRAME, but you can call a JavaScript function on the parent from JavaScript code in the IFRAME. It would probably easier to use one of the Ajax methods of jQuery to fetch the data. You can see the IFRAME-technique at work in the puzzle game at https://sourceforge.net/projects/hylzee/

Comment: I've made some adjustments and made the application through AJAX but there is a problem with this
"Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin "
json data appears in Firefox and does not appear in Google Chrome via the console